# Showing only target user notifications

Tags: php, if-statement, while-loop

I'm trying to get only the notification_targetuser posts to show in the while loop but its showing content from both users. I've used an if statement but it doesn't seem to have any affect so I'm wondering is there a different operator I must use.

```
<? 
include"database.php"; 
?>

<?php
$user1_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_SESSION['id']);

$call = "SELECT notification_id,notification_content,notification_targetuser,notification_status,notification_triggeredby,notification_throughurl,notification_time 
         FROM notifications 
         WHERE notification_targetuser='$user1_id' 
         AND notification_status=1 
         OR notification_status=2 
         ORDER BY notification_id DESC LIMIT 4";

$chant = mysqli_query($mysqli, $call) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
$numnote = mysqli_num_rows($chant);

if($numnote == 0){
    echo "No Notifications";
}

while($notificationchant = mysqli_fetch_assoc($chant)){
    if($user1_id == $notificationchant['notification_targetuser']){
?>
        <div class="notif_ui">
        <div class="notif_text">
        <div id="notif_actual_text-<? echo $notificationchant['notification_id'] ?>" class="notif_actual_text">
            <?
            echo "<img border=\"1\" src=\"userimages/cropped".$notificationchant['notification_triggeredby'].".jpg?photo_time=" . time()."\" onerror='this.src=\"userimages/no_profile_img.jpeg\"' width=\"40\" height=\"40\"><a href='".$notificationchant['notification_throughurl']."'>".$notificationchant['notification_content']." </a><br />";
            echo "".Agotime($notificationchant['notification_time']).""; 
            ?>
        </div></div></div>
<?}}?>
```

Comment: Can you explain in brief what problem you are facing and what do you want

Comment: Yes. I am only wanting the results from notification_target user printed as 4 results from the while. It is working but only showing 1 result instead of 4 as asked for in the query.

Comment: Are you sure there are four results in the database if you run that query outside of the PHP code?

Comment: Yes it does. I've worked out when I add the LIMIT 4 in it shows only 1 result and when I take that out it shows all the results but there is far too many, so it is working. Its as if the LIMIT isn't working.

Answer (score -1):

use `==` instead of `=` in your if condition

use this

```
if($user1_id==$notificationchant['notification_targetuser'])
```

instead of

```
if($user1_id=$notificationchant['notification_targetuser'])
```

**UPDATE 2 :**

also upldate your sql (remove unserscore `_` in variable after `$`)

`WHERE notification_targetuser='$_user1_id'`

To

`WHERE notification_targetuser='$user1_id'`

Comment: Yes I tried that originally but it only shows 1 result instead of 4 and there is literally about 40 results in the database for that user as I test constantly.

Comment: @Dave may be there is one record only in your database with your condition applied in sql. try to execute you sql in your phpmyadmin directly

Comment: Ok when I take the LIMIT 4 out it works how it should but has so many results I have to scroll for about 20 seconds to get to the bottom. this is bizarre.

Answer (score -1):

Change this

```
if($user1_id=$notificationchant['notification_targetuser']){
```

To This

```
if($user1_id==$notificationchant['notification_targetuser']){
```

The `==` is a comparison, whereas `=` sets the variable.

**Update:**

You may also want to look at the WHERE in your sql. It is a different user variable than you assigned.

> WHERE notification_targetuser='$_user1_id'

**Update 2:**

Try changing this

```
WHERE notification_targetuser='$user1_id'
```

to this

```
WHERE notification_targetuser='".$user1_id."'
```

Comment: That was my bad. before I add that I always use session['id'] and edited it when I posted this, only with the extra _ which was a typo

Comment: If you have that WHERE clause in your sql. Why do you need the if statement to also check it? Won't it always be true?

Comment: That is what I thought, but I can't understand why it isn't working as its also showing the notification_triggeredby content too.:/

Comment: Try changing this `WHERE notification_targetuser='$user1_id'` to this `WHERE notification_targetuser='".$user1_id."'`